# Spring applies a custom bean naming strategy when?

Tags: spring

1. auto wiring is disabled and bean name is not provided
2. dependency checking is enabled and dependency exists for a bean in different context
3. using specific annotations that do not contain name value
4. bean is defined with alias and not  id.
5. auto wiring is enabled and bean name is not provided.

I am preparing for a certification in spring .Found these question in Dumps.
Please help in getting answers.